# SQL injection attack simulation does not work properly

Tags: oracle, sql-injection

I saw in a tutorial that in order to simulate a SQL injection attack instance in JDBC, it writes the following statement in **SQLite** with double quotes and then records are loaded. But when I write the same phrase in **oracle** with a single quote, it gives an error. Why?

```
//in main
System.out.println("Enter a title:");
DB.querySongArtistView(scanner.nextLine());

//in database class
private static final String QUERY_SONG_ARTIST_VIEW = "SELECT ARTIST , ALBUM , TRACK FROM SONG_ARTIST WHERE TITLE ='";


public Optional<List<SongArtist>> querySongArtistView(String title) {
    List<SongArtist> songArtistListView = null;
try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(QUERY_SONG_ARTIST_VIEW + title + "'")) {
        songArtistListView = new ArrayList<>();

        while (resultSet.next())
            songArtistListView.add(new SongArtist(resultSet.getString(1),
                    resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getInt(3)));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        displayExceptionMessage(e);
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(songArtistListView);
}
```

Things that the tutorial entered as input:

```
Go Your Own Way" or 1=1 or ";
```

my query in oracle:

```
Go Your Own Way' or 1=1 or ';
```

error:

```
[42000][920] ORA-00920: invalid relational operator Position: 62
```

The query that I expect to work but it does not:

```
SELECT ARTIST, ALBUM , TRACK FROM SONG_ARTIST WHERE TITLE ='Go Your Own Way' or 1=1 or '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about the `or ''` part - that empty string needs to be compared to something (which is a bit tricky as oracle treats it as null).

It should work with something like:

```
Go Your Own Way' or 'X' = 'X
```

which would generate

```
SELECT ARTIST, ALBUM , TRACK FROM SONG_ARTIST WHERE TITLE ='Go Your Own Way' or 'X' = 'X';
```

[which is valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af26354ea7660feb565d74c888fce270), at least.